# Does the term "malware signature" always refer to a pattern of bytes?

Tags: malware, antivirus, antimalware, detection

I know that traditionally a malware signature is a pattern of bytes in a program. While reading Joxean Koret and Elias Bachaalany's "Antivirus Hacker's Handbook" I saw that the authors categorized the use of call-graphs and flow-graphs in malware detection as forms of signature-based detection.

Is it accepted that call-graphs and flow-graphs could be considered signatures? If so then what is the general definition of a malware signature?

Comment: signature could be anything that might uniquely identify a malware.

Comment: I'm writing an essay on this topic. Is there a good source I can cite for this definition?

Comment: Refer :  'www.emis.de/journals/IJOPCM/files/IJOPCM%28vol.1.2.3.S.08%29.pdf'

Comment: @nocut This appears to be a good paper, but that definition of signature is not in it.

Comment: The duplicate is as close as you are going to get. The term has no formal definition, but it is far more than a byte string, in general, although you can find evidence of some AV vendors saying that a signature is a byte pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary that a pattern of bytes in the code of malware represent the signature.

A signature in general, helps us identify the malware uniquely based on its characteristics. Below are the characteristics that go into consideration while defining a signature for the malware.

- **Network Based**: This includes comparison of network traffic with known
  IOC's (IPs) that are categorized as Command and Control servers
  controlling the Botnet(infected hosts). **ex**: Trojans, APT
- **Host Based**: This checks port scans over the network to increase
  the foot hold by infecting other hosts. **ex**: Worm
- **Application Based**: This checks for presence of strings in a program
  that can do privilege escalations , cause OS corruption, importing
  critical DLLs that are in general not required. **ex**:  virus

There is also [**Heuristic detection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_analysis), that is used to define the signature of a malware.

Based on the above detection methods, if any of the symptoms are seen by the malware, it is categorized in that major signature type like  Worm, Trojan, Heuristic etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a good source I can cite for this definition? I need one because I am writing an essay on the topic.